# $I$ a maximal ideal in ring $R$ if and only if for all $a \in R\setminus I, \exists r\in R, b \in I$ such that $b+ar=1$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals

Let $R$ be a commutative Ring with $1\neq 0$. Let $I$ be a proper ideal of $R$. Show that $I$ is maximal $\iff$ for all $a \in R\setminus I$ there are $r\in R$ and $ b \in I$ such that $b+ar=1$.

I'm not sure how to approach proving this.

Comment: *Hint*: Consider the ideal generated by $I$ and $a \in R \setminus I$.

Comment: Note that the condition $b+ar=1$ exactly means that $a+I$ is an invertible element in $R/I$. So if you know that $I$ is maximal if and only if $R/I$ is a field then you easily solve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

To show $\Rightarrow$, let $I$ maximal and $a \in R \setminus I$.

Then $\langle I, a \rangle \supsetneq I$. Since $I$ is maximal, what must $\langle I, a \rangle$ be? Do you see why this shows $1 = b  +ar$?

To show $\Leftarrow$, we use a slick trick: recall $I$ is maximal if and only if $R/I$ is a field (see [here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Maximal_Ideal_iff_Quotient_Ring_is_Field) for a proof).

Then for some $a \in R \setminus I$, saying $b+ar = 1$ is saying exactly that $ar = 1 \text{ (mod $I$) }$. Do you see how to show that $R/I$ must be a field, and thus $I$ must be maximal?

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: Thanks, I understand now! I wasn't thinking about quotient rings.

Comment: Actually, could you explain why $\langle I,a \rangle=R$ implies that $1=b+ar$?

Comment: $1 \in R = \langle I, a \rangle$. So $1 = si + ra$ for $i \in I$ and some eleemnts $r,s \in R$ (this is the definition of "ideal generated by"). Since $I$ is an ideal, we see $b = si$ is already in $I$. Proving the claim

Comment: @omegadeeznuts I added an answer independent of quotient rings (it is helpful to know both ways),.

Answer (score 2):

It is helpful to view this as an ideal analog of $\,B\,$ prime, $\,B\nmid A\Rightarrow \gcd(A,B) = 1.\,$ Indeed, in PIDs  we have $\, B\supseteq A\iff B\mid A\,$ and $\,A+B = \gcd(A,B)\,$ (and similarly in Dedekind domains). Keep this analogy in mind when reading the generalization below.

**Theorem** $\ $ The following are equivalent for an ideal $\,B\,$ in a commutative ring $\,R$.

$(1)\ \ A\not\subseteq B \Rightarrow \ \, A\,+\,B = (1)$
$(2)\ \ \ a\not\in B \Rightarrow\ (a)+B=(1)$
$(3)\ \ \ a\not\in B \Rightarrow\ \  ar\,+\,b\, =\, 1,\,$ for some $\,b\in B.\ r\in R$
$(4)\ \ \,B\,$ is a maximal ideal

**Proof** $\ \  (1\Rightarrow 2\Rightarrow 3)\  $ clear.
$(3\Rightarrow 4)\ \,$ If $\,A\supsetneq B\,$ then there is $\,a\in A,\,a\not\in B\,$ so $\,1 = ar+b\in A\,$ so $\,A = (1)$
$(4\Rightarrow 1)\ \ $ The ideal $\,A+B\supsetneq A\,$ so $\,A+B = (1)$ by maximality of $B$.

Answer (score 1):

It is well-known that if

$I \subset R \tag 1$

is a maximal ideal, then $R/I$ is a field; and thus if

$a \in R \setminus I, \tag 2$

we have

$a \ne 0 \mod I \tag 3$

which implies $a + I$ has an inverse in $R/I$; that is, there is some

$r \in R \tag 4$

with

$ar = 1 \mod I, \tag 5$

or

$ar - 1 \in I; \tag 6$

this of course implies that

$1 - ar = -(ar - 1) \in I, \tag 7$

and thus

$\exists b \in I \; 1 - ar = b, \tag 8$

from which we readily infer that

$ar + b = 1. \tag 9$

Now suppose that for every $a$ as in (2) there are

$r \in R, \; b \in I \tag{10}$

such that

$ar + b = 1 \tag{11}$

or

$ar - 1 = -b \in I, \tag{12}$

whence

$ar = 1 \mod I; \tag{13}$

this implies that

$r \in R \setminus I \tag{14}$

lest

$r = 0 \mod I \tag{15}$

in contradiction to (13), which now implies $r + I$ is the inverse to $a + I$ in $R/I$, which is thus seen to be a field, implying $I$ is maximal in $R$. $OE\Delta$.